# Naive question about lepton/quark energy states

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, quarks, leptons

I understand there are 3 energy states for quarks and leptons (electron, muon, tauon... Up, charm, top etc.)

And we have 3 forces (not including gravity, em, strong and weak).
This naively seems coincidental to me.

I understand that the 3 forces have their own associated particles (gauge bosons)..

But is there something in the standard model that ties the quark/lepton energy states to the three forces.

Why, are there three types of electron?
Might an electron be linked to the em field, a muon to the weak force and a tauon to the strong force, regardless of whether they all share photons as their gauge boson.. if you see what I mean?

Is there some model, like string theory etc which makes a link between particle energy states and gauge fields?

Might neutrinos not exist at all.. but instead tauon to muon energy loss be a product of interaction with a field other than the em field etc.

This would seem to be a way to simplify things?

Or am I just way off?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89152/discussion-on-question-by-richard-naive-question-about-lepton-quark-energy-state).

Answer (score 2):

What you have called "energy states" are actually called flavors. And the ensemble of four particles (electron, neutrino, up and down quarks) that is repeated three times is called a generation, so there are "three generations".

There are a lot of threes in fundamental physics, e.g. three space dimensions and three quark colors, and sometimes people hope to give them a common explanation, or just unify them somehow. Thus there are theories in which flavor is like color and there are "family gauge bosons" which can change electron into muon, etc (but these new bosons have to be very heavy or else we would already see their effects), there is a "trinification" unified theory, and so on.

But I never heard of someone trying to explain the three generations as having a correspondence to the three forces. And it would be hard to do because other physics "threesomes" involve things that can be interconverted or rotated into each other, like the dimensions of space, or the colors of quarks, or the generation flavors in a theory with family bosons.

The three forces are not really like that. For example, they each have a different number of force bosons, because their symmetry groups have a different number of generators. So you can't just swap them, the way you can with e.g. directions in space, or generations of particles.

If you were trying to derive the other "threes" of fundamental physics from the existence of three forces, you might have to start with the overall standard model symmetry group, then employ some kind of "index" (mathematical function) that counts the number of factors, but use the index in a form where it is a vector space (this is how some index quantities work), so that number of factors turns into number of dimensions of the vector space. And then that index vector space would have to be at the root of flavor symmetry and perhaps other threeness.

Part of your intuition was also that the different mass scales of the generations, are related to the different coupling strengths of the forces. Again, it's just barely thinkable that this could work. The index as I have described it loses all information about what the force symmetry groups are, and just outputs the number of forces, but there could be an auxiliary quantity which counts the number of generators, and perhaps that could be mapped to force strength and to mass scale of each generation.

Having come this far, I guess I'd say that your concept could conceivably be carried through. But I don't think it could happen in ordinary quantum field theory, it would have to come from some more combinatorial foundation that gives rise to QFT in the continuum limit.

Comment: That there are lots of experimentally visible force bosons is a fly in the ointment I accept. And I know deep in this are things I don't understand like 'spinners'.
Your description of indices sounds like an idea I had, which is that the key to this might be in concentrating not on a description of what things 'are' but in how the different things 'become' other things. In other words, to model energy state transition, rather than stability  of visible results in different energy states. So concentrate on modelling how tau becomes muon not on modelling muons and taus. if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Its an intetesting idea. But there are lots of 3's in the standard model. Some of them are just coincidences. When you get twolarge numbers that match up then it is more interesting. There may indeed be a 4th force with group like SU(3) that acts on family but it hasn't been discovered so far although there are some tantilising hints from the lhc...

Comment: Yeah. I saw a Roger Penrose interview in which he discussed that.